# Chrome is opening new Window instead of new tab when Ctrl+N is pressed

Tags: google-chrome

I am using **Chrome** version *44.0.2403.155 m* in Windows 7 when I press Ctrl+N it opens new window instead of new tab. How to open new tab in same window with keyboard?

Comment: Two things: 1. This is not relevant to stack overflow and two, it's Ctrl+T.

Comment: Where should I post this question?

Comment: try super user http://superuser.com/

Comment: How can I move this question to superuser.com? or I have to post new question on superuser.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ctrl+T opens a new tab. Ctrl+N is supposed to open a new window.

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl+T opens a new Tab. Ctrl+W closes it. These work in all browsers.

[Here](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179?hl=en) are more shortcuts for Chrome.